# Access granted and denied

Tags: c#, string

How can I tell the program to give access only if I enterd the correct password?

Thank you.

```
namespace Password
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter password:");
        Console.ReadLine();



        string Password = "Test";
        bool PassWordMatch;

        PassWordMatch = Password == "Test";

        if (PassWordMatch)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(" Password Match. Access Granted");

        }
        else
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Password doesn't match! Access denied.");

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just for the record: this is not robust security. Anyone who really wanted "in" could either just view the IL to see what the expected password is, or if you made it trickier (stored only the hash, etc) they could decompile it, *change the IL*, and recompile it. If this is only meant to prevent the most unmotivated users, then fine. It won't keep a good dev out.

Comment: Please don't do this if you are trying to secure anything of actual value in a real application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not assigned the read string to a variable, so it is further unavailable for comparison.

[Console.ReadLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) function can be used to read the next line of characters from the input stream, or returns  `null` if no more lines are available.

You could do it as below:

```
namespace Password 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter password:"); 
            string password = Console.ReadLine(); //Assign user-entered password 
            bool passWordMatch;

            passWordMatch = password == "Test";

            if (passWordMatch)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Password Match. Access Granted");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Password doesn't match! Access denied.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Console.ReadLine` method which will return the value entered by the user and you could store it in the corresponding variable:

```
namespace Password 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter password:"); 
            string password = Console.ReadLine();
            bool passWordMatch;

            passWordMatch = password == "Test";

            if (passWordMatch)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Password Match. Access Granted");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Password doesn't match! Access denied.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost there.

[`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) method reads the standart input strem and returns it as `string`. You just need to assing what this method return a *new string* and compare it your test password.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter password:");
string input = Console.ReadLine();

bool PassWordMatch = input == "Test";
if(PassWordMatch)
   Console.WriteLine(" Password Match. Access Granted");
else
   Console.WriteLine("Password doesn't match! Access denied.");
```

And of course, this is not a good way for security in your application.